# breaklines and blank spaces

Tags: awk, sed, tr

In file shell I have the following:

Looks like:

```
BCTS1
                             ,07/09/2021                    ,
        09:06:26                      ,09:09:26                      ,
        0 horas con 3 minutos
```

I would like it to look like:

`BCTS1,07/09/2021,09:06:26,09:09:26,0 horas con 3 minutos`

Several breaklines and blank spaces.

Can anyone help?

Comment: There seems to be a verb missing in this sentence: “_Several breaklines and blank spaces._”

Comment: Can newlines occur with fields? For example could you have `0 horas<newline>con 3 minutos` in the input? If so how should those be handled - newlines removed or replaced with blanks or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
cat file
BCTS1
                ,07/09/2021                    ,
    09:06:26                      ,09:09:26                      ,
    0 horas con 3 minutos
```

Your *easiest* substitution is with Perl:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\s*,\s*/,/g' file
BCTS1,07/09/2021,09:06:26,09:09:26,0 horas con 3 minutos
```

Or, you can use `cat` `tr` and `sed`:

```
cat file | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*/,/g'
# same output
```

Or with any POSIX awk:

```
cat file | tr -d '\n' | awk '{gsub(/[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*/,",")} 1'
```

With GNU sed:

```
sed -Ez 's/\s*,\s*/,/g' file
```

Comment: You can go with a single `sed` too: `sed -Ez 's/\s*,\s*/,/g'` (I suspect that line-buffering might misbehave for large files, but other solutions are equally suspect, except maybe Perl which I’m not familiar enough with).

Comment: The `cat file |` solutions have a UUOC and the `tr -d '\n'` convert the input into something that's no longer a valid POSIX test file so YMMV with what any subsequent text-processing tool does with that.

Answer (score 0):

Using any POSIX awk

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*' -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1}1' file
BCTS1,07/09/2021,09:06:26,09:09:26,0 horas con 3 minutos
```

and if you don't have a POSIX awk (for the `[:space:]` character class) then:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'[ \t\n]*,[ \t\n]*' -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1}1' file
BCTS1,07/09/2021,09:06:26,09:09:26,0 horas con 3 minutos
```

The above assumes that, like in the example you posted, you don't have any blank lines in the input. If you do then you could use this with GNU awk (for multi-char RS and `\s` shorthand):

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= -F'\\s*,\\s*' -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1}1' file
BCTS1,07/09/2021,09:06:26,09:09:26,0 horas con 3 minutos
```

or this with any awk:

```
$ awk '{r=r $0 OFS} END{$0=r; gsub(/[ \t]*,[ \t]*/,","); print}' file
BCTS1,07/09/2021,09:06:26,09:09:26,0 horas con 3 minutos
```